# Function overloading and type inference in typescript

Tags: typescript, overloading

I have this type:

```
type Bar = number;
type Foo = {
   doIt: ((value: string) => Bar) | ((value: string, provideBar: (bar: Bar) => void) => void);
}
```

The idea is that `Bar` can be returned in one of two ways depending on which function signature is provided.  The code which consumes an implementation of `Foo` looks like:

```
function getBar(foo: Foo) {
  let bar: Bar = 0;

  if (foo.doIt.length === 1) { // We've been provided with the first version of `Foo`
    bar = foo.doIt('hello');  
    // The above line is erroring with: 
    // - bar: Type 'number | void' is not assignable to type 'number'
    // - invocation of "doIt": Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.

  } else if (foo.doIt.length === 2) { // We've been provided with the second version of `Foo`
    foo.doIt('hello', (_bar) => bar = _bar);
  }
}
```

Code which would provide an implementation of a `Foo` looks like:

```
function provideBar() {
  const foo1: Foo = {
    doIt: (value) => 1. // Error:  Parameter 'value' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  }

  const foo2: Foo = {
    doIt: (value, provideBar) => provideBar(2) // Appears to be working
  }
}
```

I'm hopeful typescript has a way to express what I'm trying to achieve.  I'm not sure why I'm getting these errors as, the way I see it, TS has enough information to bar able to provide type inference (I'm assuming TS can use `function.length` to deferentiate between the two ways to implement a `Foo`)

Comment: This isn't "overloading" as the term is used in TypeScript.  Overloads are essentially *intersections* of functions, while these are *unions*.

Comment: My apologies.  Ignoring my terminology, do you have any ideas?

Comment: Yeah I'm writing up an answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the issue inside `getBar()`'s implementation, you're running into [microsoft/TypeScript#18422](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18422), listed as a design limitation in TypeScript.

The compiler only sees the `length` property of a function as being of type `number`, and not any specific [numeric literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html#numeric-literal-types) like `1` or `2`.  So checking `foo.doIt.length === 1` has no implication for [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis), and thus the compiler does not know which of the two function types it is calling.

One major problem with checking `length` is that it might well not be what you think it is.  Functions can be implemented with [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters), and `length` might well be `0`.

Or because TypeScript allows you to assign functions that accept fewer parameters to those that accept more (see [this FAQ entry](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters)), it's possible that a function that matches `(value: string, provideBar: (bar: Bar) => void) => void` might have a `length` of `1` or `0` because function implementations are free to ignore any of their inputs.

Because of such weirdness around `length`, TypeScript basically doesn't do anything and recommends that you don't try to check `length` this way.

Still, if you are confident that the check does what you think it does (that is, nobody will set `"doIt"` to one of the "gotcha" versions above), you can get similar behavior by implementing a [user-defined type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards):

```
function takesOneArg<F extends Function>(x: F): x is Extract<F, (y: any) => any> {
    return x.length === 1
}
```

The `takesOneArg()` function checks the `length` of its function-like argument of type `F` and returns `true` if it equals `1` and `false` otherwise.  The return type predicate `x is Extract<F, (y: any) => any>` means that if `F` is a union of function types, a `true` result means that the type of `x` can be narrowed to just the members of `F` that take one argument; and a `false` result means `x` can be narrowed to the other ones.

Now your `getBar()` implementation works as expected:

```
function getBar(foo: Foo) {
    let bar: Bar = 0;
    if (takesOneArg(foo.doIt)) {
        bar = foo.doIt('hello');
    } else {
        foo.doIt('hello', (_bar) => bar = _bar);
    }
}
```

---

As for the issue when you *create* a `Foo` where you see an implicit `any` error in the callback argument, this seems to be [microsoft/TypeScript#37580](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37580).  You would like `value` to be [contextually typed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) as `string`, but the compiler is not doing so.  There's not a lot of info in that GitHub issue, so I can't say what's causing the poor interaction between the function union and contextual typing inference.

Assuming this doesn't get fixed anytime soon, the workaround is the same one I'd always recommend with implicit `any` problems: explicitly annotate the thing the compiler can't infer:

```
const foo1: Foo = {
    doIt: (value: string) => 1
}
```

That now compiles without error.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.7#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)

Comment: Just processing your answer.  Thanks for taking the time to write out such a detailed one.

Comment: Damn, such a shame about the `Foo` creation issue... in reality the `Foo` type is much more complex and takes generics (of which inference is super important in reducing code noise.  Infact, some of the types being used are from 3rd party libs which don't always `export` the required type!).