# function that repeats other function with different parameters each time in Typescript

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a function that I want to repeat each time with different arguments and want to wrap it in another function to do some additional steps on it. Ideally, this would work for any function depending on the length of arguments like follows

```
function chainOr<T>(method: (...arg: T[]) => string, args: T[][]): string {
    return "(" + args.map((arg) => method(...arg)).join(") OR (") + ")";
}
function printDoubleArg(arg: string, arg2:string) { return arg + arg2 }
console.log(chainOr(printDoubleArg, [['hello', 'world']]))

function printArg(arg: string) { return arg }
console.log(chainOr(printArg, ['hello', 'world']))
```

but Here I am getting error `Type 'string' is not assignable to type '[arg: string]'` for the second function call

Unfortunately I don't understand what [arg:string] is supposed to represent and how I could write it so that it just expects string

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBAFgQxmA8gJwDwAqAfABQC2AplCnACYBciJAdK2jgOaMEDaAugEpEAXiKIAzlByYOAGkTsO47v34DGk6WA6IA3gCgAkDiogcSAEQkLiANQLO45mTQAHEiUVDRiStTosbJwCAswAVnCY1kJYAEpMFkL2iRYA3PoAvvqgkLAIiK5aUAAicCAARgA2FACCnJ6cGlIy8ooATPSaMkK6iCZQZkiKdg4cbYhZEAjicNXMlXAcJKgY2DgkhZglZVW1nPI8PADkKBSVC0fyRwDucDiVtEd8ggL62eDQ8EibYFB1S4omloOD0+qZzKMJvopmAZnMFksVphcBsiv8Diczhcrrd7o8XkA)

Comment: Your `method` looks like it takes a single argument, so `(...args: any[]) => string` is not the right type.  And `Parameters<T>` would be a list of parameters when you only have one, so presumably `Parameters<T>[0]` would be better.  But this example doesn't need the function type itself to be generic; the only generic here is the type of the single argument to the function.  So [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WzOGLw) would be my suggestion. Does that work for your needs or are you looking for something else here?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Unfortunately I might have multiple parameters for my function, sorry I should have chosen a sample function that shows that. I suppose I could live with (this approach)[https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBAFgQxmA8gJwDwAqAfABQC2AplCnACYBciJAdK2jgOaMEDaAugEpEAXiKIAzlByYOAGkTsO47v34DGk6WA6IA3gCgAkDiogcSAEQkLiANQLO45mTQAHEiUVDRiStTosbJwCAswAVnCY1kJYAEpMFkL2iRYA3PoAvvqgkLAIiK5aUACCnJ6cGlIy8ooATPSaMkK6iCZQZkiKdg4ctYhZEAjicAA2FMwjcBwkqBjYOCSFmCWc8jw8AOQoFCOTG-IbaBxzG3xrGwDucDgjtKeCAvpAA] but would it be possible to allow single params too?

Comment: Could you [edit] the code in the question to be a [mre] that demonstrates the actual thing you're trying to do?  How would it "allow single params too" in practice?  Would  `chainOr(fn, [x, y])` call `fn` twice with params `x` and `y`, or would it call it once with param `[x, y]`? How would an implementation of `chainOr` tell the difference? Ideally you will provide an implementation of `chainOr` and I can help you with the typing.  If you are happy with array-of-arrays only you can do [this](https://tsplay.dev/mZG11W), but otherwise I need an explicit description of your intent.

Comment: Thanks, I would have hoped that TS would figure out how many elements fn requires and if it's only one expect it to be passed the arg rather than arg[]. Ive updated the question and the playground

Comment: Unfortunately the question doesn't describe the situation anymore; you are ostensibly asking about `[arg: string]` but no such error appears anywhere; could you fix that so that the question is as clear as possible about what the issue is?

Comment: About your hope that "TS would figure out how many elements fn requires", that's not how it works. TypeScript is (mostly) just a static type system on top of JavaScript, and this is completely [erased](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types) from the emitted JavaScript.  If you want something to happen at runtime, you need to write the code that does it.  Do you have some idea of what you'd want that runtime code to look like? It would be nice to limit the scope of the question to a single issue.

Comment: If this *does* turn out to be about inspecting functions for how many arguments they expect, I'd direct you to https://stackoverflow.com/q/66082625/2887218 .  But I hope it's not, since the question as originally asked didn't seem to be about that at all, and scope creep isn't fun.