# Currying in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to define types for a currying function in TypeScript. The JavaScript version is as follows:

```
function curry1(fn) {
  return (x) => (fn.length === 1 ? fn(x) : curry1(fn.bind(undefined, x)));
}
```

This works perfectly well -- applying `curry1` to a function produces a unary function. If you call that function with an argument, it will produce another unary function, that when called with an argument will produce yet another unary function, etc., until all parameters have been provided, in which case it will produce a result. Currying `f1` below produces a function equivalent to `(a)=>(b)=>(c)=>result`.

```
const make3 = (a, b, c) => `${a}:${b}:${c}`;

const f1 = curry1(make3);
const f2 = f1('A');
const f3 = f2(2);
const f4 = f3('Z');

console.log(f4);  // A:2:Z
```

I defined a generic `CURRY1` type that essentially returns a function that will produce a result (if given a unary function) or a curried function with one fewer argument (if given a function with two or more arguments).

```
type CURRY1<P extends any[], R> = P extends [infer H]
  ? (arg: H) => R // only 1 arg?
  : P extends [infer H0, infer H1, ...infer T] // 2 or more args?
  ? (arg: H0) => CURRY1<[H1, ...T], R>
  : never;
```

and then

```
function curry1<P extends any[], R>(fn: (...args: P) => R): CURRY1<P, R> {
  return (x: any): any => (fn.length === 1 ? fn(x) : curry1(fn.bind(undefined, x)));
}
```

If I write

```
const make3 = (a: string, b: number, c: string): string => `${a}:${b}:${c}`;
```

and write `f1 = curry1(make3)` VSCode correctly shows that the type of `f1` is `(arg: string) => (arg: number) => (arg: string) => string`. However, TypeScript objects, saying `Type '(x: any) => any' is not assignable to type 'CURRY1<P, R>' ts(2322)`. If I add a `// @ts-ignore` line before the `return`, the code works perfectly well. ***But how can I avoid having that error otherwise?***

Comment: The type annotations on the inner returned function don't agree with the return type annotation of the outer function.

Comment: I simplified the type to 
`type CURRY2<P extends any[], R> = P extends [infer H, ...infer T] ? (arg: H) => CURRY2<T, R> : R;`; not sure if it is fully right.

I think the issue may just be that typescript is not 'smart' enough to realise that any array will eventually terminate with an R value. Maybe those more familiar with the type system will be able to resolve this issue.

Comment: Somewhat of an aside: note that `//@ts-ignore` is almost never warranted for typing issues like this, since all it does is suppress the *display* of the error.  Instead you should use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) where needed.

Comment: You cannot avoid problems like this when your function returns a generic conditional type; the compiler tends to completely defer evaluation of such types, so it doesn't know if or when a value will be appropriate; see [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) for an authoritative source.  ...

Comment: ... For now I'd suggest an implementation like [this](//tsplay.dev/w6L2Gm) where you use a one-call-signature overload to split the function into the strongly-typed call signature and the loosely-typed implementation. This isn't any more safe than a type assertion, but it shows the separation of concerns nicely.  If this fully addresses your question I could write up an answer explaining; otherwise, what am I missing? (Pls mention @jcalz to notify me if you reply).

Comment: @AluanHaddad -- what type annotations do you mean?

Comment: @yanjunk I tried your simplification and it works exactly like mine (good!) but still produces the same error for which I added the `@ts-ignore`, I'm sad to say.

Comment: @jcalz This is an interesting approach --  I'm wondering if it could be applied to a more generic type of currying in which you allow to bind more arguments at a step:
`function curryN(fn) { return (...x) => (fn.length === x.length ? fn(...x) : curry1(fn.bind(undefined, ...x))); }`

Comment: You could certainly do something there (like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wXzR9m) maybe), but that seems like a followup question and thus out of scope here.  Right now I'm asking if my approach would constitute an acceptable answer to your question as asked; if so, I'll write it up.  If, after that, you want to know more about `curryN` and can't figure it out, you could post a new question for it if you want.

Comment: Thanks, @jcalz -- your solution is acceptable, so please write it up. The question about curryN stands, though; I'm not sure I can see how the curry1 solution would be generalized for that.

Comment: I gave you [this solution](https://tsplay.dev/wXzR9m) for `curryN` in the comment; are you saying you don't understand how it works? Or did you not notice it?  (Either way it's probably out of scope here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In what follows I'm going to rewrite your types like this:

```
interface Curry1<AH, AT extends any[], R> {
  (firstArg: AH): AT extends [infer ATH, ...infer ATT] ? Curry1<ATH, ATT, R> : R;
}

declare function curry1<AH, AT extends any[], R>(
  fn: (firstArg: AH, ...restArgs: AT) => R
): Curry1<AH, AT, R>;
```

This is essentially the same as what you've got, but it makes it impossible to even pass in a zero-argument function (there's always a first argument of type `AH` (the `H`ead of the `A`rguments tuple).

---

It isn't currently possible for the compiler to verify that `curry1` is implemented properly, since it needs to return a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that depends on as-yet unspecified [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters `AH`, `AT`, and `R`.

The check `fn.length === 1` could conceivably have a [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) effect on the value `fn` (although TS doesn't actually do this, see [Function overloading and type inference in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66082625/2887218) for more info), but it has no effect whatsoever on the type parameter `AT` (the `T`ail of the `A`rguments tuple type).  There is currently no mechanism whereby [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) does anything to re-constrain type parameters.

And so, for example, even if `fn.length === 1`, the type `AT` is not re-constrained to the empty tuple `[]`, and so `AT extends [infer ATH, ...infer ATT] ? Curry1<ATH, ATT, R> : R` cannot be simplified to `R`, and so `fn(firstArg)` is not seen as a valid return value.

There is an open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) asking for better support here.  But for now, the best you can do is equivalent to a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to suppress the compiler errors inside the implementation.

---

Usually in cases like this, I tend to write the function in question as an [overloaded function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) with a *single* call signature.  Overloads require you to declare the call signatures, and then write a separate implementation.  This implementation is checked against the call signatures somewhat loosely, and so it is a rather convenient way to separate the concerns of the callers (who want useful strong types) and the implementer (who wants to implement the function and move on with their life).  It is this slightly-off-label convenience I'm taking advantage of here, not the as-advertised ability to have multiple call signatures.

Anyway, it would look like this:

```
// call signature with strong typing
function curry1<AH, AT extends any[], R>(
  fn: (firstArg: AH, ...restArgs: AT) => R
): Curry1<AH, AT, R>;

// implementation signature with (relatively) loose typing
function curry1(fn: (...args: any) => any) {
  return (firstArg: any) => (fn.length === 1 ? fn(firstArg) : curry1(fn.bind(undefined, firstArg)));
}
```

You can see that I'm using `any` a lot in the implementation; the type checker is unable to verify what I'm doing as safe, so I'm mostly asking it to stay out of my way.  That also means I need to be careful with the implementation, since any mistake I make will not be caught by the type checker.

---

Okay, let's try it out:

```
const make3 = (a: string, b: number, c: string) => `${a}:${b}:${c}`;    
const f1 = curry1(make3);
const f2 = f1('A');
const f3 = f2(2);
const f4 = f3('Z');    
console.log(f4);  // A:2:Z
```

This all behaves as you want and expect, since it only depends on the call signatures.

Note that the implementation isn't completely safe, since there's only a loose relationship between the [`length` property of a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length) and the number of arguments passed to it.  Functions can have optional elements (the function `(a = 1) => a` has a length of `0`) and rest parameters (the function `(...args: any[]) => args)` also has a length of `0`), and sometimes TypeScript has a different idea about the number of arguments than JavaScript does ([the `Math.max` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max), for example has a `length` of `2`, even though it's variadic and TypeScript sees it as if it were `0`).  So you can get some weird edge cases:

```
const oops = curry1(Math.max);
const oops2 = oops(2); 
// const oops2: number;
oops2.toFixed() // error! oops2.toFixed is not a function
```

If this matters, I think the only safe option is to change your currying so that there's an explicit "call the function" step somewhere.  But that's out of scope for the question as asked, so I won't go into it further.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9&ts=4.8.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIFcpQJ4EYA8AggBIA0yhAKshAB6QgAmAzsnCNgNoC65ASgD5kAbwBQyZAAoYwKMzCEoAcwBcFYgEo1VGvQhNWnUDGgVKZZADprx01UrdkAfjSYcBKhfv8havgG5RAF9RUQB6MOQEOAAbGORmYCUQODBMFAB3YDAACwSwKAB7ECVkMGwAB1AlURh0EAQwYGKotzwiL2o6BhY2Dh4faRA1aVl5RVV1cmtLKAhx5WZtSg1kAF4hPi1XLHaSciofQPDI4ABbCpiIM-0wVOaQBKSUtLnkLNypOZj7gDcIGLYVYxQqFZgocpVEq1eqNB6tXa4IYjGZwRZqdhA9ZCTGrMQSOavR6jOQKZQYjirDZSGAgSxXEqfNbM5C4ZzIWkkhZKVZqBBtJG0ywAI1AjEk9UYEBkIAgjHIMlJEw0KsCIVECGK8mQZzgAGsIABmdZSOBqeRQarkYVqEDoM7C6DkBDmgrVKlCAAGABJhHAgipfcKA76EEFPcdNSBtTA2WsEe5JLqDYaNIEozGAEwm2OSADkhDzaY1WrAHON8ZgmckmeLGbLMAALDnDfmAFpFyNawpXemFJTSRtpiQRCgqTMqNuhEvRnsQPsDySSOAm3Aetgaen6JS5VajgAMM+Yc4XS8kqPRfS43HXaKUzE3DJ3OT3kUPoQzJ5BA4AsqkcpYuq0FujIvv4yCjpmR5lqCFSsPG-KIpIf65IBcC0HWpbILBzDZvGOE1sWOGZpYYCFAAYsAtBypIr40FghRQAAhNhhRwSRZGUdRjDIMArAgIUZYrnUDRNMUoRAA)

Comment: Excellent and clear explanation, @jcalz  - many thanks!!